# How to provide delay in audiotrack?

Tags: android, audiorecord, audiotrack

I have created a talking tom like app where the users voice get repeated in real time...
I have referred this tutorial http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-audio-demo-audiotrack.html?showComment=1399963972392#c1419513985405584589 
but it replies to the voice immediately and after changing the code
i.e. track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, 9000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter*19, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

It gives me delay only for sometime and after that it immediately reply to my voice.
It I maintain 8000hz frequency in audiotrack it reply properly but I don't want reply in that frequency ....
I have gone through latency concept But I didn't find any proper solution

I am stuck Plzzzzzz help me in this ..
Thanks in advance....

Comment: You won't achieve delay with the audio track constructor. You should either wait before creating the track, or wait before feeding the buffer. In both cases you will need to use Thread.sleep()

Comment: hii schmop.
 thanks.
 can you please give me a snippet...

Answer (score 1):

Insert a delay by pausing your thread before track creation:

```
try {Thread.sleep(delayInMilliSeconds);}
catch (Exception e) {}

track = new AudioTrack(...);
```